# I can't consume the message from kafka using KafkaConsumer in spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

```
@Override
public void getKafkaUserFeedback() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, group);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, consumeKey);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, consumeValue);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offset);

    try (KafkaConsumer<String, UserFeedBackRequest> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props)) {
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("open-user-requests"));

        while (true) { // Continuously poll for messages
            ConsumerRecords<String, UserFeedBackRequest> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, UserFeedBackRequest> record : records) {
                try {
                    // Process and store the message into the database
                    System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
                    // saveMessageToDatabase(record.value());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Handle any processing errors
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle any Kafka consumer errors
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    }
```

I am always getting the records.size = 0. But when I using this @KafkaListener(topics = "open-user-requests", groupId = "test")
public void abv(UserFeedBackRequest userFeedBackRequest) throws JsonProcessingException {
log.info("Received JSON string: {}", userFeedBackRequest.toString()); // Log the JSON string
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
} I am getting my expected result

I am trying to consume the message from kafka here. But i am getting 0 result. But the message are store in kafka topic